# Thumbnail image different to actual image

Tags: gallery, images, thumbnails

A similar question has been asked previously, however the answer is not relevant to my problem.

I have a number of photos where the thumbnail in the gallery does not match the photo displayed by the viewer (HTC Sensation, stock gallery and photo viewer).

for instance, take a picture of a child on a swing.

The thumbnail appears to be an image taken a fraction of a second earlier than the photo the viewer presents. The child is framed to the right of the photo in the thumbnail but to the left in the full view.

Is anyone able to explain why this is the case?

Also, am I able to rescue the image presented as the thumbnail (which is a better framed image)?

Comment: What question? How is your question different than that other question? (It's not that I don't believe you, but to keep from being closed as a duplicate you need to show the differences.)

Comment: Both previous questions regarding thumbnails not being the same as the actual image refer to images that have been deleted. This is in no way part of my question. My question relates to an image which appears to be taken a fraction of a second before (constituting the thumbnail) the image which the 'Gallery' presents to you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my OP5T running android 8.1. While you don't seem to be able to obtain the original images, the thumbnails can be found as low-res jpgs at:

> storage/interrnal storage/DCIM/.thumbnails

Depending on what you need them for, you might still be able to use the images.
I hope my answer was helpful.